# Google App Engine Always On feature

Tags: google-app-engine

Can someone explain what is the Always on feature in Google App Engine ? How is it useful? An explanation with example will be appreciated.

Does Always on feature work even for task queues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, Google shuts down app engine app instances when they have no traffic. With this feature, you can pay extra to have an instance always running. This saves time during traffic spikes as time does not need to be taken to launch a new instance.

Comment: This is especially useful for Java apps, which can take a lot of time to launch (more than ten seconds).

Comment: When your code is running, google app engine creates instances to keep your code running. When there is heavy traffic, the instances are always available and the requests will be served faster. When there is very less traffic, these instances die after sometime. So when new request comes in, GAE has to load up these instances first before serving the request which will take some time (not significant amount of time but still measurable amount)