# Issue with Cloud App Engine, Jersey REST framework and Cloud SQL

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, rest, cloud

I have a App engine Project in Google App Engine named : cwdataproject
I also have a REST service Application deployed in Google App engine under same Project. I have Implemented REST service using Jersey with CORS implementation.REST service Application Project retrieving data from Google Cloud SQL and returning back to client.

Now, the behavior of REST service seems very unstable. Some time it is giving back result. and sometime it is not returning any data . But no error is there.

This is from App Engine log :

A 2014-05-14 11:41:27.581 200    298B 12ms
/rest/messageservices/manufecturerlist?callback=createmanufactureroption
[13/May/2014:23:11:27 -0700] "GET /rest/messageservices/manufecturerlist?callback=createmanufactureroption HTTP/1.1" 200 298 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Lenovo P780_ROW Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30" "cwdataproject.appspot.com" ms=12 cpu_ms=520 cpm_usd=0.000033 instance=00c61b117ce022f9f9bf9df99be6e4b0b6e58e app_engine_release=1.9.4

But same code was working hours back ;-) Here is a log which was returning data previously. No change has been done ..

[13/May/2014:11:23:18 -0700] "GET /rest/messageservices/manufecturerlist?callback=createmanufactureroption HTTP/1.1" 200 560 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Lenovo P780_ROW Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30" "cwdataproject.appspot.com" ms=11543 cpu_ms=7280 cpm_usd=0.000063 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117ce022f9f9bf9df99be6e4b0b6e58e app_engine_release=1.9.4

I only can see a difference **loading_request=1**

Really no idea. !!!

Can anybody help please ..

My appengine-web.xml file looks as below ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>messageframework</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <!--
    HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:

      <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
    asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:

      <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />

    With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
    stale session data. For details, see
    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
  -->
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Are you sure the request which you are sending it has data or not ?

Comment: Yes Ankur ,, It is master manufacturer list, hence will not take any input but will return all the manufacturer as output

Comment: Some problem must be there in your code. As I have deployed several applications on GAE using Spring, Hibernate, Objectify and I never faced any such issue.

Comment: I have noticed an unusual pattern.. Services are working fine for sometime ..and if i send request continiously, it works,, and suppose I have not send request for longer period of time.. then it will stop returning the result. and again If i restart the instance, it start to return service result. Need help. to understand. And these behaviour is observing for those seervices which are intaresting with cloud sql database. there are two services which are not interesting with database, those are working always.

Comment: This is happening because you are using the free instance of your GAE application, when you switch to Paid Version there is an option of keeping instance always on, then your service will work continuously.

Comment: I have billing enabled for this GAE project. I have already 3 USD billed on it. I will not be able to use Cloud SQL qithout billing activated. I have found I need to do a shoutdown of instance at https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~cwdataproject/appengine/instances and then on the very next request it is restarting the instance and send the proper response back. But if i kept idle for one hour without any request. then from then onwards I am not getting any response back. again I have to restart the instance to get the response back. Need help to solve it out :(

Comment: You need to keep your appengine application instance alive as well, so you need to enable billing for this appengine app as well.

Comment: You can check these related links as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054026/gae-pricing-always-on-feature-and-instances-charging and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754744/google-app-engine-always-on-feature

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thanks for your response. but I have checked and "Billing Status: Enabled" for this app. Is there any other process to keep appengine application instance alive. I have checked the pattern again , if I restart the instance, it is giving result, but after some idle time it is stopping to return result.  these are GET operation and returning JSONWithPadding object as @Produces("application/x-javascript") to support CORS ..is there anything wrong in it.